# VBA allowing Macro on protected worksheet

Tags: vba, password-protection

Does anyone know if there is a way to allow VBA to run macros on a protected worksheet without writting the password in the code itself?

```
    Sub UnProtect_Modify_Protect()

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="Password"
'Unprotect

  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Changed"
'Modify

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password"
'Protect

End Sub
```

What I am afraid of is the macro running into a bug right after unprotecting the worksheet, this would leave it unprotected indefenitely.

Thanks.

Comment: Add an error handler!

Comment: It looks like you read the linked thread based on your provided code snippet. Did you overlook the answer(s) that discussed `UserInterfaceOnly`?

Comment: @BigBen Yes I read the part where someone comments regarding an improvement and he also posts an improved version of the macro, but unfortunately it wasn't clear to me if the improvement was 100% fail proof or not

Comment: To answer "without writing the password in the code itself" - no. Well theoretically you could by reading the password stored in an external file, or could obfuscate the code, but generally either using `UserInterfaceOnly` or not, the password will be hard-coded.